# Is the hadith of Ibn Abbas about six haram things authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

I came across the hadith below today. I am curious as to whether this hadith is sahih or hasan or daif because I have never seen it before used in debates.

Arabic:

> 2193 - قال مسدد: حدثنا أبو عوانة عن أبي هاشم، عن ابن عباس رضي الله عنه قال: "الكوبة (1) حرام، والدف (2) حرام، والمعازف (3) حرام، والمزامير (4) حرام (5) ـ
>
> <sup>Possible source: [stream](https://archive.org/stream/FPmazmt/mazmt10#page/n230/mode/2up) - [pdf](https://ia802304.us.archive.org/17/items/FPmazmt/mazmt10.pdf) (page 230)</sup>

There is also this version:

> عن ابن عباس أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم حرم ستة الخمر والميسر والمعازف والمزامير والدف والكوبة
>
> [(المعجم الاوسط ، رقم ۷۳۸۸)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/7723#p1)

I found this thread (https://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=28650) where I believe this hadith is being addressed; however, unfortunately I do not understand Arabic and am unable to understand what is being written. Can someone kindly let me know?

JazakAllah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hadith is daif. Moulana Suhail Motala writes:

> "‘Allamah Dhahabi (rahimahullah) has declared a narrator unknown (majhul). This narration will therefore be deemed weak.
>
> (Al Muhaddhab of ‘Allamah Dhahabi, Hadith: 16210)"

https://hadithanswers.com/abdullahs-ibn-abbas-radiyallahu-anhuma-ruling-regarding-drums-and-musical-instruments/

The second hadith is daif. Moulana Suhail Motala writes:

> "Imam Tabarani (rahimahullah) has recorded this Hadith. ‘Allamah Haythami (rahimahullah) has declared one of the narrators extremely weak.
>
> (Al Mu’jamul Awsat, Hadith: 7384, Majma’uz Zawaid, vol. 5 pg. 53)"

https://hadithanswers.com/nabi-sallallahu-alayhi-wa-sallam-deemed-six-things-forbidden/